# Android: List all installed apps and get total running time of each app

Tags: java, android

How to list all installed applications with total running time of each app and show it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your Android Manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

And after that you can get a list of apps installed with this function:

```java
public static List <ApplicationInfo> getUserInstalledApplications(Context context) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List < ApplicationInfo > installedApplications =
        packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for (ApplicationInfo appInfo: installedApplications) {
        //Do what you want with app info
    }
}
```

Comment: ok and how to display apps info and total running time of each app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of each service's start time by using ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.[activeSince](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html#activeSince).

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

 long currentMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();        
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo info : services) {
     cal.setTimeInMillis(currentMillis-info.activeSince);

     Log.i(TAG, String.format("Process %s with component %s has been running since %s (%d milliseconds)",
             info.process, info.service.getClassName(), cal.getTime().toString(), info.activeSince));
 }
```